# Remove first duplicate element of a list

Tags: python, list

I need to remove the duplicate occurrence of the 1st element in the list which is duplicate (present more than once) while preserving the order of the input list. For eg: for the input of 
    in = [2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 6, 4, 1]
output should be 
    out = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 1]

I have tried below and is giving correct result , I just wanted to check with the community if there is a better or more pythonic solution to this

```
input = [2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 6, 4, 1]
first_dupe = None
for elem in input:
    if input.count(elem) > 1:
        first_dupe = elem
        break

flg = True
new_list = []
for x in input:
    if x != first_dupe or flg is True:
        new_list.append(x)
        if x == first_dupe:
             flg = False

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to remove the first duplicate, you can create set, append elements to a new list if they are in the set while removing each element from the set as well.  When an element is not seen, append the rest of the list.

This is fairly efficient if the duplicate is seen early, but has `O(1)` if the element is seen late.

```
x = [2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 6, 4, 1]
s = set(x)
out = []

for i,z in enumerate(x):
    if z in s:
        out.append(z)
        s.remove(z)
    else:
        break

out += x[i+1:]

out 
# returns:
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could keep track of what you have already used and check if the value is in there.

```
lst = [2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 6, 4, 1]

used = set([])
for i, x in enumerate(lst):
    if x in used:
        lst.pop(i)
        break
    used.add(x)
print(lst)
```

Also, don't give variables, or anything else, the same name as a keyword in python. `input` is already a built-in function.

Comment: It's better for `used` to be `set`.

Comment: This is better than the original solution, but: 1. Iterating using `for i in range(len())` is not pythonic. 2. `used` could probably be a `set`.

Comment: Thanks, I guess the best alternative would be `enumerate`?

Answer (score 0):

This is my version of Chiheb Nexus' answer.

```
def find_dup(lst):
     seen = set()
     it = iter(lst)
     for item in it:
         if item not in seen:
             seen.add(item)
             yield item
         else:
             yield from it

lst = [2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 6, 4, 1]
list(find_dup(lst))
```

---

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 1]
```